# How to put into a drop down data in my scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in a registration system and I created a module where user can create leagues. Now, in registering a team in a particular league, I want to put into drop down option all the league names that was created.

This is what I got so far

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
  <option><%= team.team_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

This is in my form_html.erb in the team folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form_for or simple form

Does teams belongs to league and a league has many teams, right? So in your controller create action you must call:

```
@leagues =  League.all or League.where(anything: :anything_param)
```

than on your form (create edit teams) you must call. This will provide a select option where :league can be selected.

```
<%=  f.association :league ,collection: @leagues %>
```

Than you will provide actions to connect your league to your team.

Comment: I will put @teams = Team.all or Team.where(anything: :anything_param) in my leagues controller, def create?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your relation, I edited and this may work now. If you have any doubt you can send me a message andrelzgava@gmail.com. I see that you're learning I don't know much but I can help you :D

Comment: Does this solved your problem? If yes please mark my answear as solution :D